# Spring CORS. Add pattern in the allowed origins

Tags: java, spring, cors

Seeing the spring guides of CORS, the following code enable all allowed origins:

```
public class MyWebMVCConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

And for multiples origins, the method allowedOrigins permits more than one  domain, eg:

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com", "http://domain2.com");
```

So, it's possible use a regular pattern in allowedOrigins? At my work I need to test a REST service in a develop enmviroment and their host is variable in the moment of creation, eg: http://www.devXXXXXX.company.com where XXXXXX is a random number.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring 5.3 you can use [setAllowedOriginPatterns(@Nullable
List allowedOriginPatterns)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedOriginPatterns-java.util.List-).

However, it does not accept RegEx, but rather a wildcard pattern where you can use '*' for any character sequence and [xxxx] for ports.

In your case, the pattern would be http://www.dev*.company.com

Unfortunately, as this is using a wildcard pattern instead of regex it means that it's not as strict and origins like http://www.devdevdev.company.com would also be matched.

Answer (score 1):

[`com.ge.predix.web.cors.CORSFilter`](https://github.com/predix/spring-cors-filter) [has a mechanism](https://github.com/predix/spring-cors-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ge/predix/web/cors/CORSFilter.java#L60) to allow you to specify a comma-delimited list of regular-expression origin patterns using a `cors.xhr.allowed.origins` property.

You can put the `cors.xhr.allowed.origins` property into [an `application.properties` file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

```
cors.xhr.allowed.origins=http:\/\/www\.dev[0-9]+\.company\.com
```

Comment: can you share a full example?