# Setting API cookies in SPA

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, cookies, single-page-application

## Context

I am writing a SPA in which the frontend and the backend are served from different domains:

- `mywebsite.com`
- `myapi.com`

To keep things simple I am trying to use cookies for authentication. When signing in, the server responds with a `set-cookie` header, as shown below:

[image: Sign in response]

When making subsequent requests to the API, the cookie should be included to make sure the user is authenticated. For instance:

[image: Request]

## Problem

This all works well when serving the API on `localhost:5000` and the frontend on `localhost:4200`, but it doesn't work when deployed. As you can see in the screenshots below, the `sign-in` response has the proper `set-cookie` header, but the cookie doesn't seem to be set by the browser, and therefore is not sent in future requests.

Response after signing in:

[image: Response (Google)]

Subsequent request:

[image: Request (Google)]

## Question

Is there a way to make this work with two different domains? Or is it forbidden for security reasons? Would it work if I used subdomains, as in `mywebsite.com` and `api.mywebsite.com`? Would it work with two subdomains, as in `frontend.mywebsite.com` and `api.mywebsite.com`?

Comment: It seems that you're making cross-domain requests. Your BE should allow the specified origins in it's config or you can use a reverse-proxy.

Comment: I'd like to investigate the option of allowing the specified origins. How does that work? Is there a specific http header I can use?

Comment: that depends on the BE you're using. For nodejs it's something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915776/5706293 for spring-boot it might be like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165186/5706293 .net: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942128/5706293

Comment: I'm using ASP Core as backend with a correct CORS configuration. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is automatically set to the origin on which the frontend is running (http://localhost:4200 locally, and https://mywebsite.com when deployed). Are you suggesting this needs to be changed?

Comment: Nope, if the FE is running on mywebsite.com it seems correct

Comment: are you setting `withCredentials` to `true` when making the requests?

Comment: Yes. I think the basic configuration must be right, because it all works when I run things locally (which it didn't at the beginning, because I was missing stuff like `withCredentials`)

Comment: The problem section still shows the origin as localhost:4200 tho, is that intended? I thought it only didn't work when deployed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231753/discussion-between-aochagavia-and-eko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I discovered I was using the wrong `SameSite` configuration for the cookie (`samesite=lax`). According to MDN, `samesite=lax` means that *cookies are not sent on normal cross-site subrequests (for example to load images or frames into a third party site), but are sent when a user is navigating to the origin site (i.e. when following a link).*

Using `samesite=none` solved the issue, since it means *cookies will be sent in all contexts, i.e in responses to both first-party and cross-origin requests*.